# Why is it allowed to modify argv[0]?

Tags: linux, perl, procfs, spoof, cmdline-args

I have been working on a project that uses PIDs, `/proc` and command line analysis to validate processes on a system. My code had to be checked by the security guys who manage to break it with a single line... embarrassing!

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

$0="I am running wild"; # I had no clue you can do this!

system("cat /proc/$$/cmdline");
print("\n");
system("ps -ef | grep $$");

# do bad stuff here...
```

My questions:

1. I see some uses cases for the above, like hiding passwords given on the command line (also bad practice) but I see a lot more problems/issues when one can hide processes and spoof `cmdline`. Is there a reason it is allowed? Isn't it a system vulnerability?
2. How can I prevent or detect this? I have looked into `/proc` mount options. I also know that one can use `lsof` to identify spoofed processes based on unexpected behavior, but this won't work in my case. At the moment I am using a simple method to detect if the `cmdline` contains at least one null (`\0`) character which assumes that at least one argument is present. In the above code, spaces need to be replaced with nulls to bypass that check which is something I couldn't find how to implement in Perl - writes up to the first `\0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer 1:

It's because of how starting a new process actually works.

You `fork()` to spawn a duplicate instance of your current process, and then you `exec()` to start the new thing - it replaces your *current* process with the 'new' process, and as a result - it *has* to rewrite `$0`.

This is actually quite useful though when running parallel code - I do it fairly frequently when `fork()`ing code, because it makes it easy to spot which 'thing' is getting stuck/running hot.

E.g.:

```
use Parallel::ForkManager;
my $manager = Parallel::ForkManager -> new ( 10 ); 

foreach my $server ( @list_of_servers ) {
    $manager -> start and next;
    $0 = "$0 child: ($server)";
    #do stuff;
    $manager -> finish;
}
```

You can instantly see in your `ps` list what's going on. You'll see this sort of behaviour with many multiprocessing services like `httpd`.

But it isn't a vulnerability, unless you assume it's something that it's not (as you do). No more than being able to 'mv' a binary anyway.

Anyway, to answer 2... prevent or detect what? I mean, you can't tell what a process is doing from the command line, but you can't tell what it's doing otherwise anyway (there's plenty of ways to make a piece of code do something 'odd' behind the scenes).

The answer is - trust your security model. Don't run untrusted code in a privileged context, and it's largely irrelevant what they call it. Sure, you could write rude messages in the process list, but it's pretty obvious who's doing it.

Comment: Hi Sobrique. I see what you are saying and I admit I am using the `cmdline` probably for something I shouldn't (see [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34380618/password-management-for-non-interactive-process)). I also see the usefulness of it in parallel processing. My second question is more about if I can detect that the cmdline has been modified to something other than the first/original value

Comment: But that's every process.  The "parent" of every process on your system is ultimately `init`. Everything else did a fork and exec from there - and in the process, changed its name. Files don't know their own name, names are just how the directory structure finds a particular inode. So processes don't know their own name either,  aside from setting $0 to something appropriate.

Comment: I see... makes sense... and I was afraid that it would be the case - I accept your answer since you cover both questions. The technical info you provide is also very much appreciated  - cheers for that :)